# employee sick leave table using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I couldn't figure out what the problem which cause "type mismatch" error when i click the command button for the first time it shows the error , when i click again it works fine. so can u help me to figure out what cause this error

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const cStart As Long = 5
    Const cEnd As Long = 6
    Const cDura As Long = 8
 ' Define Workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

   Dim srg As Range 'range refer to cell/multiple cells/row/column
    Dim Sec As Range
    Set srg = wb.Worksheets("info").Range("A2").CurrentRegion 'all data
     Set Sec = wb.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
     ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value  'variant any type of data
     Dim Dataa As Variant: Dataa = Sec.Value
     Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(Data, 1) ' Source Number of Rows , UBound return size of array
     Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2) ' return Number of Columns
     
     
     
      ' Define Days Array.
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(2 To srCount) 'array, ReDim increase number without deleting previous data
    Dim countDura As Variant: ReDim countDura(srCount)
    Dim rrCount As Long: rrCount = 1 ' Result Array Row Counter - 1 for headers
    Dim cDiff As Long ' Days Between First and Last incl.
    Dim dura As Long
    Dim i As Long ' Data (Source) Array Rows
    Dim d As Long
    
      ' Calculate Result Array Rows Count and populate Days Array.
    For i = 2 To srCount
        cDiff = DateDiff("M", Data(i, cStart), Data(i, cEnd)) + 1
        dData(i) = cDiff
        rrCount = rrCount + cDiff
    
    
    Next i
    
    For d = 3 To srCount
    dura = Data(d, cEnd) - Data(d, cStart)
    countDura(d) = dura
    rrCount = rrCount + dura
   
    Next d
      
    
     ' Define Result Array.
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To rrCount, 1 To cCount)
    Dim k As Long: k = 1 ' Result Array Rows Counter - 1 for headers
    
     ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim j As Long ' Data and Result Array Columns Counter
    Dim n As Long ' Repeat Counter

' Write headers.
    For j = 1 To cCount
        Result(1, j) = Data(1, j)
    Next j

 ' Write 'body'.
    For i = 2 To srCount 'row
    
        For n = 1 To dData(i) 'diff

            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To cCount 'column
                Select Case j
                Case cStart  'column 5 (started date)
                    If dData(i) = 1 Then  'print the same dates if the diff is 1
                        Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                        Result(k, cEnd) = Data(i, cEnd)
                        
                         Else
                        If n = 1 Then
                            Result(k, j) = Data(i, j) 'the first row of diff then change last date of month
                            Result(k, cEnd) = dateLastInMonth(Data(i, j))

                            Else
                            If n = dData(i) Then 'if n = diff , change first date depnd on last date(last row of diff)
                                Result(k, j) = dateFirstInMonth(Data(i, cEnd))
                                Result(k, cEnd) = Data(i, cEnd)
                                Result(k, cDura) = Data(i, cDura)

                                 Else ' previous empty row
                                Result(k, j) = Result(k - 1, cEnd) + 1
                                Result(k, cEnd) = dateLastInMonth(Result(k, j))
                                 Result(k, cDura) = Data(i, cDura)

                                   End If
                                   End If
                                   End If

                Case Is <> cEnd  ' not equal

                    Result(k, j) = Data(i, j) '' print rest of data
                    Result(k, cDura) = Data(i, cDura)
                    
    
                End Select

                  
            Next j
        Next n
    Next i
  
    With wb.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").Resize(, cCount)
        .Resize(k).Value = Result
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - k + 1).Offset(k).ClearContents
         
         Dim shDest As Worksheet
         Set shDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("new")
         Dim last_row As Long
         last_row = shDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
         Dim daysDura As Long
         Dim countDur As Variant: ReDim countDur(last_row)
       
            For i = 2 To last_row 'row
               shDest.Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
               daysDura = DateDiff("d", Dataa(i, cStart), Dataa(i, cEnd))
               countDur(i) = daysDura
               shDest.Cells(i, 8).Value = countDur(i)
              Next i

   End With
 
End Sub

Function dateFirstInMonth( _
    ByVal d As Date) _
As Date
    dateFirstInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
End Function

Function dateLastInMonth( _
    ByVal d As Date) _
As Date
    If Month(d) = 12 Then
        dateLastInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), 12, 31)
    Else
        dateLastInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) + 1, 1) - 1
    End If
End Function
```

The code is to shows the leave dates and calculate the number of days between the dates

Comment: What is the value of `Dataa(i, cStart)`and `Dataa(i, cEnd)` when you look at it in the debugger?

Comment: I agree with @MGP. My guess is that Range("A1").CurrentRegion may consist of only one cell on first run which leads to Dataa not be be an array. In one way or another it's that Variant thnat causes the problem. Step into the code break point and F8 and look at the values in the Locals window.

Comment: I changed the range but still the same error. the column and row number are the same in the first and second press, but in the first press it shows mismatch but in the second press it works fine.!!! @Variatus

Comment: Nobody suggested that you "change the range". The recommendation was to look at what it contains. Learn about debugging. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx?em_x=22

Comment: i know the line which cause the error and how to debug it but i couldn't fix it, i am still new in vba macro @Variatus

Comment: Then answer @MGP's question.

Comment: Type mismatch means, that the data you plug into the function `DateDiff` isn't a date... therefore it would help if you would set two watches and see what the values are... otherwise it is difficult to say what the cause of the error is.